# Matrix multiplication of 2 different sizes in matlab

Tags: matlab, matrix

I am having a matrix of size i*j. I want to perform operations to give a new matrix.
i.e, m11+4m21+m31.
m-matrix.
m11-1st row 1st column
m21- 2nd row 1st column.
The value obatined above is a11.
a- new matrix
a11- 1st row 1st column.
I need to perform these operations for every row and column.
Can any one please guide me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your question is vey unclear, but it looks like you may want

```
conv2(m, [1;4;1], 'valid')
```

Example:

```
>> m = [1 3 4; 5 4 3; 8 3 9; 3 5 0]
m =
     1     3     4
     5     4     3
     8     3     9
     3     5     0

>> conv2(m, [1;4;1], 'valid')
ans =
    29    22    25
    40    21    39
```

Answer (score 0):

If `A(1,1) = M(1,1) + 4*M(2,1) + M(3,1)`, then all we can give you is that `A(1,1) = [1 4 1]*M(:,1);` The same operation for each column `A(1,1:3) = [1 4 1]*M`. The same operation for each row I assume gives the same answer. So if `A(2,1)` is equal to `A(1,1)', 'A = [1 4 1;1 4 1;1 4 1]*M`. As Luis Mendo suggest - not a very clear question.

Comment: Thank you for your response. Sorry for the inconvenience. Example:

Comment: Thank you for your response. Sorry for the inconvenience. But i got the answer for the problem. Thank you and sorry once again.

Comment: No problem, but don't forget to mark it as an answer..